# RESTful routing best practice when referencing current_user from route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have typical RESTful routes for a user:

```
/user/:id
/user/:id/edit
/user/:id/newsfeed
```

However the `/user/:id/edit` route can only be accessed when the id equals the current_user's id. As I only want the current_user to have access to edit its profile. I don't want other users able to edit profiles that don't belong to them.

What is typically the best practice to handle this situation?

Should I leave the route as is, and thrw an error if the `current_user.id != param[:id]`, forcing the front end client calling the api to track the logged in user's id?

Should I make a special route `/user/self/edit` and in the controller check to see if `param[:id] == 'self'`?

Comment: The standard rails way would be to check the id against current user in before_filter/before_action or do as the accepted anwer and load resource based upon current_user

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would've added special routes for current user profile actions, in this case you don't have to check anything. Just load and display the data of current user. For example:

```
/my-profile/edit
/my-profile/newsfeed
```

It's not that RESTful but you don't have to put extra checks keeping your code clean.

If you still have to have (or want to have) a strict RESTful routes then I would use a before_filter and check if the id = current_user.id. If not then return 401 or 403.

Comment: Well, you could consider `/profile` to be a resource, and I would even rename the second url to just `/newsfeed`, which is the current-user's newsfeed.

Answer (score 5):

> I only want the current_user to have access to edit its profile. I
>   don't want other users able to edit profiles that don't belong to
>   them.

What I suggest is to use some **authorization gems** like [**pundit**](https://github.com/elabs/pundit)

***Sample code:***

```
class UserPolicy
  attr_reader :current_user, :model

  def initialize(current_user, model)
    @current_user = current_user
    @user = model
  end

  def edit?
    @current_user == @user
  end
end
```

Also with an **authentication gem** like [**Devise**](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), only the `current_user`(the users who logged in) can only access and edit their profiles

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you are doing it correctly, just keep your current route as it is right now. And what you should do is to add a restriction in your controller instead. I would assume that you are using Rails, and working on users_controller.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController::Base
  def edit
    if current_user.id == params[:id]
      # do your work
    else
      render :404
    end
  end
end
```

Or you could clean up your controller by moving the restriction into a callback instead:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController::Base
  before_filter :restrict_user, only: [:edit]

  def edit
    # do your work
  end

  private
  def restrict_user
    render :404 unless current_user.id == params[:id]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `gem "cancancan"` and after the initialize....

```
    class Ability
        include CanCan::Ability

        def initialize(user)

            can :update, User do |user|
                 user.id == params[:id]
            end
        end
    end
```

Then add this `authorize! :edit, @user` to your update action

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to add authorization code in all the user_controller methods as another comment suggested. Usually what I do in apps where a user is only supposed to edit their own profile I add a /profile route for a user to edit their own profile and then on the main /users/:id/* routes I add logic to prevent non-admin users from accessing those routes.

Answer (score 2):

User is able to view his profile `/users/1` or edit his profile `/users/1/edit`. From users perspective this URLs are absolutely fine.

There is no links which may lead user to edit the another user. You are trying to cover the different situation: when someone manually trying to craft the URL and get access to another account. I would not call them hackers, but technically they are – users who are trying to exploit your website to pass the restrictions.

You don't have to worry about "hackers" convenience. I'm always use `current_user` in `edit` action so nobody can edit wrong profile whatever his profile is.

```
def edit
  @user = current_user
end
```

Also, I need to mention that you should also cover `update` action with such checks. With `edit` you may only get data (and probably only wide-public open data, unless you put billing information or plain-text-passwords inside your `edit` template). But with `update` you can actually change the data, which may be more destructive.

Answer (score 2):

Because it seems that the only available user resource should be the authenticated user, I think the best way to solve this is

```
GET /user
PUT /user
GET /user/newsfeed
```

If you like to extend the api usage in future so that one user could have access to other user resources, than you need a solution that includes the user ids. Here it makes sense to introduce the routes for "self", too. But then you also have to implement an access check on server side.

```
GET /user/id/:id
PUT /user/id/:id
GET /user/id/:id/newsfeed

GET /user/self
PUT /user/self
GET /user/self/newsfeed
```

But I think you should keep it as simple as possible

For further investigations I would propose books like http://apigee.com/about/resources/ebooks/web-api-design which give a good introduction into API design

Answer (score 1):

Since you only care to provide RESTful endpoints **only** for the currently authenticated user, which is available in your controllers as `current_user`, i say you don't need the `id` identifier parameter. I suggest using the following routes:

```
GET /user => users#show
PUT/PATCH /user => users#update
GET /user/edit => users#edit
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the url as it is. Authentication and Authorization are separate concerns. 'current_user' refers to the user who is authenticated to access the apis. The id in the url identifies the resource on which 'current_user' is working, so does he have access to that resource or not is the concern of authorization. So you should add `current_user.id != param[:id]` (as you mentioned) in your api permissions and throw 403 status code in response.

Answer (score -1):

You should use this route:

```
PUT /user/me
```

Note that there is no need for "edit": you should use the `PUT` method instead.

Also, you should explicitly define the route I've written above, instead of checking if `id == 'self'`.